# Remote desktop shows distorted graphics

Tags: 14.04, graphics, xfce, remote-desktop

I'm having trouble with setting up a remote desktop on my Ubuntu 14.04 desktop using xrdp and xfce. I'm trying to log in from a laptop running 15.10 using Remmina.

I have set it up as described in [this tutorial](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5305), and I am able to successfully log in and see the desktop, move files around, and so on, but the desktop looks absolutely horrible:

[image]

[image]

I have tried to look for ways to resolve this issue but I'm having a lot of trouble diagnosing the distortion of the graphics. Any help towards diagnosing this problem will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Can you add a bit more info? In particular, what graphic card do you have in each system? Are you using propietary/x.org drivers? A priori, this smells like a bug to me. See here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/remmina/+bug/1006300

Comment: The built-in one on the laptop ("2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller") and a Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series on the desktop. I do not remember changing any drivers from the default installation, but I'm unsure where to look to confirm this.

Comment: Well, since you have Intel drivers on the laptop, there is no alternative driver to use (so far as I understand). You can check this in Settings, Additional Drivers. If it is empty, then you have the only drivers for them. I don't see why changing the drivers in the desktop would help, but you can always try. By default, you have open source drivers for ATI (x.org). You can try the proprietary ones (which might be less stable for other applications, as it is my case). For full information about how to change them check here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD (it is easy)

Comment: So this is is the laptop drivers that could be causing the problem? Or the desktop ones? How would the laptop drivers intervene?

Comment: I don't know. I would bet it is the laptop, but without alternative drivers I don't know how this can be tested. You can test the desktop ones, by changing the driver from X.org to ATI proprietary. Do that as indicated in the link and let's see how it goes. I cannot think of any other cause. Keep in mind the first link I gave you. There is an unresolved bug with problems like the one you have. Thus, this might just be a bug. In that case, you can create a new bug alert in Launchpad (and link it to the old one). Check https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs for more info.

Comment: OK, cool, thanks for your help. I'm not sure I'll be able to switch drivers on either, but I'll report if I can do it. I was sort of hoping that it would be just an xrdp / xfce issue, but apparently not.